# Why does Python always return a shortened path from a file object?

Tags: python, windows, path

I have the following code.

```
with TemporaryFile(mode='w', encoding='UTF-8', delete=False) as output_file:
    output_file.writelines(output)
```

When I set a breakpoint PyCharm on the second line, and examine `output_file.name` I get.

`C:\\Users\\JOHN~1.SMI\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\tmp1iv00w2n`

This isn't too useful for me, the Python program needs to return this string for other programs to use, I would like to have the full correct path.

After some Googling I discover, `os.path.realpath` but this gives the same result when applied.

How can I get Python to give me?

```
C:\Users\john.smith\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1iv00w2n
```

Comment: Python is returning the name of the file according to the file system. Windows maintains a separate mapping of valid 8+3 names to longer file names.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the correct path? My guess is that the `C:\Users\john.smith\AppData\Local\Temp\tmp1iv00w2n` isn't the correct path.

Comment: You can try this function: `os.path.expanduser`. See [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser)

Comment: Thanks for the comments. The best answer I found was in the question @MauriceMeyer linked to. Install pypiwin32 via PIP, import win32file, and then use `win32file.GetLongPathName(path)`. My code is not going to be run cross platform, so it works for me.

Comment: The tempfile module gets the default temp directory from one of the following environment variables `TMPDIR`, `TEMP`, or `TMP` -- in that order. Check their definitions.